# Read a cell with getBinaryStream

Tags: java, jdbc, inputstream

I have a varchar2 typed column1 in my database table .
I read this column from java

```
 java.sql.ResultSet r = s.executeQuery("Select * from table1");
 InputStream  is = r.getBinaryStream("column1");
```

I do something after this code. But I could not read whole value

Below text is my row.

> "Called Latent Semantic Indexing because of its ability to correlate semantically related terms that are latent in a collection of text, it was first applied to text at Bell Laboratories in the late 1980s. The method, also called latent semantic analysis (LSA), uncovers the underlying latent semantic structure in the usage of words in a body of text and how it can be used to extract the meaning of the text in response to user queries, commonly referred to as concept searches. Queries, or concept searches, against a set of documents that have undergone LSI will return results that are conceptually similar in meaning to the search criteria even if the results don’t share a specific word or words with the search criteria."

But I could read only this part of it

> Called Latent Semantic Indexing because of its ability to correlate semantically related terms

Why I could not read whole of it ?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you're not fully reading the [`InputStream`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html). A common beginner's mistake is assuming that [`InputStream#available()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) returns the length of the stream and then only that amount of bytes is been read. This is not correct. You need to read it fully until [`InputStream#read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28%29) method returns `-1`. See also the [Java IO tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). Another possible cause is that the text contains newlines and you're using [`BufferedReader#readLine()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) to read it and it is been called only once. This is also not correct. You need to call it in a loop until it returns `null`.

But as it's a `varchar` field, why don't you just use [`ResultSet#getString()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getString%28java.lang.String%29)?

```
String column1 = r.getString("column1");
```

Comment: I use a library and the method which I use take parameter as InputStream , so I must use Inputstream.

Comment: Report it as a bug to the library maintainers so that they fix it.

Comment: Ok then How should I use InputStream ? Could you give me an example ?

Comment: I've already answered that. Read until `read()` method returns `-1`. I've even given a Java IO tutorial link.